# Pod Installlation Getting Long Time and Not Install

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I am trying to install Cocoapods, and it kind of hang while downloading `AlamoFire`!
Anyone have faced similar issue?

1) Open terminal

2) sudo gem install cocoapods 
    sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

3) pod setup

4) create a xcode project

5) cd "path to your project root directory"

6) pod init

7) open -a Xcode Podfile

8) pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'

It just feel like hanged and not sucessfull even after long wait!

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: I think You have to wait for a while it does take a long time to install pods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this one in your pod file ->

```
**source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
target 'Pod DemoTests' do
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire'
end**
```

this will solve your problem ..

Answer (score 1):

pod Installation

1.sudo gem install cocoapods
2.pod init
3.import needed framework in podfile
4.pod install
5.open with workspace.